How can I add an error msg for This To-DO list problem
HTML
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Add your Task"><br>
  <span id="errmsg"></span>
  <button onclick="addTask()">Add</button>
</div>

JS
function addTask() {
  if (inputBox.value === '') {
    document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "You Must Write Somthing!";
    return false;
  } else {
    let li   = document.createElement("li");
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    li.innerHTML   = inputBox.value;
    span.innerHTML = "&times;";
    listContainer.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(span);
  }
  inputBox.value = '';
  saveData();
}

I want to give an error in the placeholder, but it's overwriting

I'm new in JS, so I didn't get how to fix it plz help me :(

need CSS to understand this of this strange overflow....

You can simply add required attribute
and use inputBox.reportValidity() in your function.
No need to use  <span id="errmsg"></span>
==> .reportValidity() method


const inputBox = document.querySelector('#input-box');

function addTask()
  {
  inputBox.value = inputBox.value.trim(); // remove spaces around...
  
  console.clear(); // for testing.
  
  if ( inputBox.reportValidity() )
    {
    console.log(`add task code: '${inputBox.value}'` )
    /*
    let li   = document.createElement("li");
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    li.textContent   = inputBox.value;
    span.textContent = "&times;";
    listContainer.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(span);
    */
    inputBox.value = '';
    }
  }
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Add your Task" required>
  <button onclick="addTask()">Add</button>
</div>




Thanks for your solution. But I want to hide the placeholder text "Add your text" when the error message shows up in the input field. Then, when I start typing in the input field, the error message should disappear. I am sorry I couldn't explain it properly in the first place.
